# How to add a manifest file to my C# program in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a simple application I want to force to run in admin mode. For that, I need to edit the manifest file. I saw tutorials that show adding it by clicking on the "Project-> Add - > new Item," but there is no manifest file there for me.

I tried making my own file (and setting it from project properties as the manifest file) but I don't know what to write there so it doesn't crash.

[image: Manifest file missing]

Comment: Is this a regular console app? Manifest files are only relevant to certain application types. Why do you think you need a manifest and do you actually just want a configuration file?

Comment: If you have an exiting manifest file (somewhere - it will be have the ".manifest" extension), you can add that *via* the "Add Exiting Item" and selecting "All Files". You can can copy such a file into your project's main source folder. That file will then appear in the list when you go to the project's "Properties" settings page.

Comment: I originally tried with a Windows form application. I need to run my code in admin mode. How else can I request admin privilages?

Comment: If you can't find a "stencil" manifest file, then create a text file and change the extension to ".manifest". There are a number of example contents of a manifest that can be found on the web. The format is essentially XML.

Comment: I tried that but it always crashed

Comment: To be able to create it from a built-in template, check if you have the ".NET desktop development" Workload installed, or else maybe the "Universal Windows Platform development" Workload. This can be done using the VS Installer that you can open from inside VS through menu `Tools -> Get Tools and Features...` and then tab `Workloads`.

Comment: Not so sure how to get this exact item list.  But it looks like a mis-click, add the item to the project instead of the solution.  Least error-prone way is to right-click the project node in the solution explorer window > Add > New Item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step 'hack' that should work; it allows you to take a copy of the default embedded manifest and modify that accordingly.

First, add a new XML file to your project *via* the "Add -> New Item ..." command and call it (say) "Elevate.xml". This will, ultimately, be the custom manifest.

Next, to get the current (embedded) manifest, (re)build your project and open the target (.exe) file from within Visual Studio. This *should* open that file in "Resource Explorer" mode, similar to the below image:

[image]

In that explorer, open the "RT_MANIFEST" node and double-click on the revealed "1 (Neutral)" sub-node; this will open a new window with the program's embedded current (default) manifest displayed as a binary resource. The manifest is actually in XML text format, and you can select that text from the right-most column (ignoring a few leading/trailing non-printable data), as show here:

[image]

Copy that selection, open your earlier "Elevate.xml" file, remove all its existing content and "Paste" the manifest resource data; this will give you content similar to that shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

You can then change the "asInvoker" level to "highestAvailable", save that file and rename it (in the project tree) to "Elevate.manifest". You can then select that custom manifest in the project's properties:

[image]

I have tested this method on a local (but very trivial) sample program, and it seems to work: when I run the program, the system *does* ask me for Administrator credentials. If you have any issues, then maybe there are some minor tweaks required in your case.

Comment: That was really helpful. I will try it out

Comment: @SimonCankov Maybe, to check that the procedure is working, go through the motions but without changing the elevation level - just to be sure that your project is correctly using the custom manifest file. You can edit that ".manifest" file any time later on.