# Modify Manifest File Win32 Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi

How do I "modify / generate" a Assembly Manifests File for a Win32 application in Visual Studio 2022.

Project Properties -> Win32 Resources -> Manifest Path is set to > "Embed manifest with default settings" I could set it to use custom manifest but what I would like to do is get the one with the default settings and then modify it, but where would I be able to find the one with the default settings?

Comment: Project > Add New Item > Application Manifest File.

Comment: That worked, I guess I'm just a bit blind because I did look before and could not find it for whatever reason -.-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a manifest file to my C# program in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600467/how-to-add-a-manifest-file-to-my-c-sharp-program-in-visual-studio-2019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution explorer > Add New Item > Application Manifest File.

[image: app manifest]