# How to edit manifest in VS2017 C++ project?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

In our application, we need to be able to determine Windows OS version. In the past, we used the `GetVersionEx()` function but it has been deprecated and it appears to stop on Win 8 (major=6, minor 2).

We'd like to use helper functions like `IsWindows10OrGreater()` but they require that apps define compatibility section in their manifests.
However, we do not know how we can edit the manifest that is automatically generated by VS2017.

There are some on-line docs that claim that you can add/edit .manifest file under Resources folder. However, we could not see such files even in newly created projects. Adding them manually does not help - they are ignored during a build process.

How should this be done?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66602142/10871073) I posted a wee while ago shows how to do something akin to what I think you want, but for a C# project. That may give you some tips. If you think it's along the right tracks but needs to be adapted for C++ projects, let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: But, IIRC, the 'default' manifest generated by the VS2017 linker already include the relevant code in the manifest to use the new `IsWin10OrGreater()` and other helper functions. Just set the "Generate Manifest" to "Yes" in the linker options property page.

Comment: @AdrianMole The manifest is generated but without the 'compatibility' section which - according to docs - is needed for helper functions to work.  When our app is run on W10 IsWindows10OrGreater() returns false. I even tried it with a brand new project where manifest by default is created and embedded. No luck.

Comment: Hmm. I have this ability enabled in most of my projects. I checked my setting when I saw this post and I have "generate manifest" set. However, I also have `ProjName.manifest` files *explicitly* included in the projects for each of the executables (those files are in the source folder of the main cpp files). I guess I edited those manifests according to the process outlined in the answer I linked. (It was all done some years ago and I haven't had to change anything, since.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-manifest-generation-for-c-cpp-programs?view=msvc-170#manifest-generation-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to add the required manifest elements to Visual C++ is to add the following file to your project:

***settings.manifest***

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
   <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
       <application> 
           <!-- Windows Vista -->
           <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
           <!-- Windows 7 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
           <!-- Windows 8 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
           <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
           <!-- Windows 10 / Windows 11 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
       </application> 
   </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Then make sure you have in your project settings:

- Linker -> Manifest File -> Generate Manifest set to YES.
- You should also have Enable User Account Control set appropriately.
- Manifest Tool -> Input and Output have Embed Manifest set to YES

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/).

Once you do this, you can then call `GetVersion`, `GetVersionEx`, `VerifyVersionInfo`, and use the VersionHelpers.h and they will all give you the "correct" answer. You will need to suppress C4996 for `GetVersion` or `GetVersionEx`, but that warning is just there due to the manifest behavior.

Of course the *real* question: WHY do you think you need the OS version number? See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/whats-in-a-version-number/).

**UPDATE**: You should not use a version check as a substitute for a feature check. If you want to know if `NetGetAadJoinInformation` is available, then use explicit linking or delay-load DLLs and check for the function before calling it.

Comment: I need to know if the app can call NetGetAadJoinInformation() which is only available in W10 and up.

Comment: Marking this as a correct answer because of a link to the first post which states that a reference a file with 'compatibility' section should be placed in “Additional Manifest Files" field of project properties.

Comment: You don't have to add it as "Additional Manifest Files" explicitly. Just being in the project does it.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not - at least not in VS2017. The build generates a default manifest without a compatibility section. This can easily be seen by checking intermediate manifest as well as the final manifest when embed is set to No.

Comment: Using VS 2017 (15.9): 1. Create a new Windows Desktop application. 2. Save the file above as 'settings.manifest' into the project. 3. Add settings.manifest as an existing item. 4. Build project. 5. Open the resulting .EXE file via "File->Open". 6. Open the RT_MANIFEST element in the resource tree view. 7. Select all and copy it into your paste buffer. 8. Paste it into notepad. The GUIDs are present.

Comment: For me with Visual Studio 2022, the "Additional Manifest Files" setting was not necessary. However, if you're building on the command line, then after changing the settings in the GUI you should do File > Save All to update the vcxproj file.